# ZIP support not found: SugarCRM needs ZIP support in order to process compressed files

Tags: apache-http-server, php, centos, sugarcrm

Ok, trying to install SugarCRM and I seem to be failing horribly.

Everything is uploaded.
Folders have write privlages (777 currently for the moment)
PHP Memory limit is at 256M
extension:php_zip.dll is uncommented

and my logs show no distinct reason for error other than what sugar is telling me which is

> ZIP support not found: SugarCRM needs ZIP support in order to process
>   compressed files

so I dunno how to get past this point, I can't seem to find much on this topic else where so here I am.

For reference I am running on

PHP 5.3.6 and CentOS 5.8 final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be sure that the zip extension is properly loading? What is the output to the phpinfo() command in the browser?

Comment: All zip related things far as I can tell short of bzip2 are enabled and working. here is the output http://fucr.org/9ux41l

Comment: I don't see the actual zip extension loaded, it should show up as a separate extension.

Comment: Which is the fun part of my problem. I have made sure perc zip is installed, zlib is enable zzip.. ive tried everything thus far to make this $*(@ work and Im coming up empty, restarted my server a few times got nothing

Comment: Are you using the stock PHP packages or a custom build?

Comment: I'm assuming originally stock. Its a dedicated server that someone else initially setup

Comment: If it's stock, your PHP build should have the zip extension by default. Does it show in the command line output of 'php -m' ?